# How to store large binary data in database

Tags: sql-server, database, optimization, filesystems, storage

I have a large document storage database in the order of 500Gb with solid binary data from files ranging from text, images , docs and pdfs etc. The database is ever increasing and as you can imagine this relational database has a single table for data storage and only a handful of tables to store the document metadata.

For sometime i have been thinking whether NoSQL would be an ideal solution for this or the current relational database with 2TB data (in future) might pose a bigger challenge later.

I had looked at couple of similar queries in this forum but nothing is conclusive hence thought of asking the following.

1. Using the current relational database (SQL Server 2012) to store the
   blob data still a good option(using standard or FileStream varbinary (max))?  [Note that I am confined to Microsoft .net stack for connectivity]
2. Is there a specific NoSQL solution handle the large data storage efficiently?
3. Conventional File System storage of documents (with filename
   stored on relational DB)  is the way to go?

[Note: public cloud is not an option.]

I am not bringing in the Data Encryption aspect as I want to source the right solution to store large number of documents (individual file sizes may be 1mb to 20 mb). Is there any merit in choosing a Database over conventional File system for storage ?

Imagine the document store to behave in a write once ready many type of scenario. For simplifying the data storage data can only be added or archived.

Comment: have you looked into FILESTREAM?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: FILESTREAM data is not encrypted .This might be an issue if we decides to enable Transparent data encryption on SQL to prevent an Inside job

Comment: You should update the question to reflect your requirement for encryption.

Comment: Also whether the transactional consistency is a must or not

Comment: eventual consistency of data is also accepted and question modified